# Change the color of messages when submitting a form using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

Someone can help me? There is a working form for sending messages to email.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" id="form" method="post" action="handler.php">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="name" class="nameForInput">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="email" class="nameForInput">Email:</label>
                <input type="mail" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" >
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone" class="nameForInput">Phone:</label>
                <input class="form-control phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="+3 (000) 000-00-00" >
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message" class="nameForInput">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="message" class="form-control" name="message" rows="5"placeholder="Enter your message" ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="myfile" class="file-label left">
          <img src="img/upload.svg" alt="">
          <p class="amount">To attach files</p>
        </label>
        <input type="file" class="my" id="myfile" name="myfile[]" multiple>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <input id="check" name="check" checked type="checkbox">
                <span class="check-text">I confirm my consent to the processing of personal data</span>
</div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
       <div class="result">
                <span id="answer"></span>
                <span id="loader"><img src="img/loader.gif" alt=""></span>
            </div>
    </form>
```

ajax:

```
var form = $('#form'),
        button = $('.btn'),
        answer = $('#answer'),
        loader = $('#loader');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'handler.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

    data: new FormData(this),

        beforeSend: function() {
            answer.empty();
            button.attr('disabled', true).css('margin-bottom', '20px');
            loader.fadeIn();
            },

        success: function(result) {
            loader.fadeOut(300, function() {
            answer.text(result);
            });
            form[0].reset();
            button.attr('disabled', false);
            },

        error: function() {
            loader.fadeOut(300, function() {
            answer.text('An error occurred! Try later.');
            });
            button.attr('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

ContactMailer.php:

```
<?php

class ContactMailer
{
    /**
     * Sender's E-mail
     * @var string
     */
    private static $emailFrom = 'somemail@mail.com';
    /**
     * Recipient's E-mail
     * @var string
     */
    private static $emailTo = 'somemail@mail.com';

    /**
     * Sends an email if the email is sent,
     * Returns TRUE, otherwise FALSE.
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $email
     * @param string $phone
     * @param string $message
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function send($name, $email, $phone, $message)
    {
        // We form a letter body
        $body = "Name: " . $name . "\nE-mail: " . $email . "\nPhone: " . $phone . "\n\nMessage:\n" . $message;

        // Create PHPMailer object
        $mailer = new PHPMailer(true);
        // Connection settings
        $mailer->isSMTP();
        // Installs the mail server host (Mail.ru: smtp.mail.ru, Google: smtp.gmail.com)
        $mailer->Host = 'smtp.mail.com';
        // Includes SMTP authorization
        $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
        // Entire login or E-mail
        $mailer->Username = self::$emailFrom;
        // Mailbox Password
        $mailer->Password = '';
        // Protocol of connection
        $mailer->SMTPSecure = '';
        // Port for outgoing mail
        $mailer->Port = '';


        // Establishes coding
        $mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        // Sets E-mail and sender name
        $mailer->setFrom(self::$emailFrom, $name);
        // Adds recipient 's E-mail
        $mailer->addAddress(self::$emailTo);
        // Control of a HTML-format
        $mailer->isHTML(false);
        // Letter subject
        $mailer->Subject = 'Feedback form completed';
        // Main body of the letter
        $mailer->Body = $body;


    // Send the letter
    if ($mailer->send()) {
        return true;
    }
        return false;
    }
}
```

handler.php:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/mailer/Validator.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/mailer/ContactMailer.php';

if (!Validator::isAjax() || !Validator::isPost()) {
    echo 'Access is forbidden!';
    exit;
}

$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['name'])) : null;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['email'])) : null;
$phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone'])) : null;
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['message'])) : null;

//protection against XSS
$name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


//Issues an error if the download size exceeds the limit set by the server
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST) && empty($_FILES) && $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > 0)
    { echo "CONTENT SIZE EXCEEDS THE LIMIT"; 
exit;}


if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || empty($message)) {
    echo 'All fields are required.';
    exit;
}

if (!Validator::isValidName($name)) {
    echo 'Name does not match format (name must contain only letters).';
    exit;
}


if (!Validator::isValidEmail($email)) {
    echo 'E-mail does not conform to the format.';
    exit;
}

if (!Validator::isValidPhone($phone)) {
    echo 'Phone doesn\'t match format.';
    exit;
}


if (ContactMailer::send($name, $email, $phone, $message)) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($name) . ', your message was sent successfully.';
} else {
    echo ' An error occurred! Failed to send message.';
}
exit;

?>
```

css:

```
#answer {
 color: #ff5b5b;
}
```

Everything works, but all messages are displayed in red because the styles for # answer are set to red. But it is necessary that in case of successful submission of forms messages are displayed in green color, and in case of errors - in red. Tried adding this:

```
success: function(result) {

            loader.fadeOut(300, function() {
            if (result === 'ok') {
            answer.text(result).addClass('success');
        }   else {
            answer.text(result).addClass('error');
        }
            });
            form[0].reset();
            button.attr('disabled', false);
            },
```

css:

```
.success {
  color: #218838;
}

.error {
  color: #ff5b5b;
}
```

but only the class 'error' is always added, and if the submission is successful as well. Also tried in the file handler.php simply stick styles to the message:

```
if (ContactMailer::send($name, $email, $phone, $message)) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($name) . '<span style="color: #218838;">, your message was sent successfully.</span>';
} else {
    echo 'An error occurred! Failed to send message.';
}
exit;
```

but nothing applies, issues just a message along with tags:

```
'<span style="color: #218838;">, your message was sent successfully.</span>'
```

Although if you create just some other php file, there the message in echo is displayed in green, does not work in this handler.php file.

Someone can suggest how to properly make the switch in Ajax so that the message is displayed green when successfully sent and why css styles are not applied in handler.php.

Comment: `echo 'Phone doesn't match format.';` need to escape ' `echo 'Phone doesn\'t match format.';`

Comment: Okay, but that 's not what I need.

Comment: Well, you'd get 500 response if the PHP file is incorrect which would trigger error part of the code. Also, I don't see where do you set `$result` as `'ok'`?

Comment: I tried setting $result as 'ok', but I don't know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It never enters the code for success because `result` is never set to `'ok'` but to a long successful message.

```
success: function(result) {
        loader.fadeOut(300, function() {
        if (result.includes('your message was sent successfully')) {
        answer.text(result).addClass('success');
    }   else {
        answer.text(result).addClass('error');
    }
        });
        form[0].reset();
        button.attr('disabled', false);
        },
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works: ` if (result.includes ('successfully')) `.

Comment: Can this be achieved with $result as 'ok '?

Comment: Well, it can, but `$result` is something that you also output as the text shown. You could create an array and return an array where the status would be `'ok'` and the message separately.

Answer (score 0):

One more way.

ContactMailer.php:

```
// Send the letter
   if ($mailer->send()) {
    return true;
     } else {
         echo 'no';
         return false;
}
```

handler.php:

```
if (ContactMailer::send($name, $email, $phone, $message)) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'An error occurred! Failed to send message.';
}
exit;
```

ajax:

```
success: function(data) {
            loader.fadeOut(300, function() {
            if (data === "yes") {
            answer.text("Your message was sent successfully.").addClass('success');
          } else {
            answer.text(data).addClass('error');
          }
          });
            form[0].reset();
            button.attr('disabled', true);
        },
```

To switch correctly before calling ajax, we also delete the answer. removeClass ('error success') class as in the example above, otherwise two classes will be added to the answer at once.

Answer (score 0):

One more.

ContactMailer:

```
// Send the letter
    if ($mailer->send()) {
        return true;
      } 
        return false;
```

handler.php:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/mailer/Validator.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/mailer/ContactMailer.php';


if (!Validator::isAjax() || !Validator::isPost()) {
    $data['error'] = 'Access is forbidden!';
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

$data = array();

$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['name'])) : null;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['email'])) : null;
$phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone'])) : null;
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['message'])) : null;


//protection against XSS
$name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


//Issues an error if the download size exceeds the limit set by the server
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST) && empty($_FILES) && $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > 0) {
    $data['error'] = "CONTENT SIZE EXCEEDS THE LIMIT";
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}


if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || empty($message)) {
    $data['error'] = 'All fields are required.';
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

if (!Validator::isValidName($name)) {
    $data['error'] = 'Name does not match format (name must contain only letters).';
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}


if (!Validator::isValidEmail($email)) {
    $data['error'] = 'E-mail does not conform to the format.';
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

if (!Validator::isValidPhone($phone)) {
    $data['error'] = 'Phone doesn\'t match format.';
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}


if (ContactMailer::send($name, $email, $phone, $message)) {
    $data['success'] = htmlspecialchars($name) . ', your message was sent successfully.';
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    $data['error'] = 'An error occurred! Failed to send message.';
    echo json_encode($data);
}
exit;
```

ajax:

```
$(function() {

  $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {


    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $('#form'),
        button = $('.btn'),
        answer = $('#answer'),
        loader = $('#loader');
        answer.removeClass('error success');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'handler.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",


    data: new FormData(this),

        beforeSend: function() {
            answer.empty();
            button.attr('disabled', true).css('margin-bottom', '20px');
            loader.fadeIn();
            },

        success: function(data) {
            loader.fadeOut(300, function() {
            if (data.error) {
            answer.text(data.error).addClass('error');
        }   else {
            answer.text(data.success).addClass('success');
        }
            });
            form[0].reset();
            button.attr('disabled', true);
            },

        error: function() {
            loader.fadeOut(300, function() {
            answer.text('An error occurred! Try later.').addClass('error');
            });
            button.attr('disabled', true);
            }

        });

    });

  });
```

In this method in ajax necessarily add dataType: "json".